# Is there a right way to build HTML through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering since a long time if there is a good way to build HTML using jQuery.

In the beggingin, I used to do things like that:

```html
var content = "";
  var footer = "";
  content += "<div class=\"row\">";
  content += "  <div class=\"col-md-10 col-md-offset-1\">";
  content += "    <p class=\"lead\">Please, give a brief explanation about why you are canceling this appointment:</p>";
  content += "    <textarea class=\"form-control\" id=\"deny_explanation\" placeholder=\"Brief explanation\" rows=\"8\"></textarea>"
  content += "  </div>";
  content += "</div>";
  footer += "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" data-dismiss=\"modal\"><i class=\"fa fa-remove\"></i> Close</button>";
  footer += "<a href=\"javascript: denyAppointment(" + appointment_id + "," + type + ");\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" ><i class=\"fa fa-thumbs-o-down\"></i> Cancel</a>";
  $("#generic_modal_title").html("Cancel appointment");
  $("#generic_modal_body").html(content);
  $("#generic_modal_footer").html(footer);
  $("#generic_modal").modal("show");
```

Then I changed to things like this:

```js
content = $('<div/>').append(
              $('<div/>').addClass('row').append(
                $('<div/>').addClass('col-md-10 col-md-offset-1').append(
                  $('<h2/>').append('Client Info')
                )
              )
            ).append(
              $('<div/>').addClass('row').append(
                $('<div/>').addClass('col-md-5 col-md-offset-1').append(
                  $('<label/>').append('Client')
                ).append($('<br>')).append(data.client.first_name + " " + data.client.last_name)
              ).append(
                $('<div/>').addClass('col-md-5 col-md-offset-0').append(
                  $('<label/>').append('Weeks pregnant')
                ).append($('<br>')).append(data.client.weeks_pregnant)
              )
            );
```

I was wondering, is there a better way to do that? My team is always confuse with the things I use to do and nothing has changed that.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Kind of off topic, but have you tried using a templating engine like Handlebars or Mustache?

Comment: I'm of the opinion you should manipultate the DOM as little as possible, therefore your fist option is better, particularly in iterative scenarios. ( http://blog.letitialew.com/post/30425074101/repaints-and-reflows-manipulating-the-dom ) . Personally I'd find the first more maintainable, but templating would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a performance perspective I honestly don't think it matters unless you are generating hundreds/thousands of these elements in a short period of time. I think the more important consideration is maintainability.

If you are building a lot of HTML from code it is strongly suggested that you use a template library for maintainability. This will allow you to separate out your UI from the code and generate components using a simple Model/View approach. A few great JavaScript template libraries that I have used in the past include:

- https://github.com/janl/mustache.js
- http://handlebarsjs.com/
- https://code.google.com/p/kite/

If you can't use a template library then it is honestly up to your team to make the call on what format they prefer. I personally would prefer the jQuery approach because it makes it easier to modify in the future while minimizing the risk of making some, hard to locate, HTML syntax error that could come back to haunt you later.

Comment: Thank you, it is very good to know. Thank you for this suggestions, I'll take a carefully view on them. It can make my team much more productive. That's very nice. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem Thiago. Good luck to you and your team!

Answer (score 1):

[Benchmarking](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-createelement) shows that `$(document.createElement('div'));` is probably the fastest way to create an element , after creating an element u can append it to any element on the DOM

Comment: Wow, that's awsome, good to know, very good. Thank you so much for that. I didn't know nothing about that. It seems that the second method is better, thank you so much.